# Add Class to Responsive Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is how to add class to responsive mobile. What I need is add this class 'scrolled' to scroll event and to `window.resize` when the window width is less than 720px. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
            $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
        }
        else {
            $('nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    });
    var width = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (width <= '720px') {
            $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
        }
    });
})
```

```css
body{
    height:2000px;
}
nav{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#10de60;
    transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
}
nav.scrolled{
    height:60px;
    background-color:#ffd800;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    my Nav
</nav>
```

Comment: the problem is i need to add class scrolled form mobile and in large screen class scrolled will be added when user scroll

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the `px`:

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (width <= 720) {
        $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

Comment: This wouldnt work since it compares number and string. Better write 720 as a number.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you want clearly. Maybe like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var width = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (width <= '720px') {
            $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
        }
      else
        {
          window.onscroll = function() {
            $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
          }         
        }
    });
})
```

```css
body{
    height:2000px;
}
nav{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#10de60;
    transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
}
nav.scrolled{
    height:60px;
    background-color:#ffd800;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    my Nav
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use media query for such purpose. This can replace the resize event.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
   .scrolled{
    //add style here
  }    
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it's not working the class scrolled when add when user scroll in large screen, and in small screens this class will be added

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query or bootstrap for mobile responsive.
[Bootstrap mobile responsive...](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Answer (score 0):

$(window).width() return numeric value but you comparing by adding '720px' so it is string that's why not working. remove 'px' and ' ' as well. Because when you putting anything between ' ' then it become a string. So try following way:

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (width <= 720) {
        $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use bootstrap 
as <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<!-- your printing statements here -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<!-- your printing statements here -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<!-- your printing statements here -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    height:2000px;
}
nav{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#10de60;
    transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
  
}
@media (max-width:720px){
nav{
overflow-y:scroll; 
  position:relative;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    my Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Navmy Nav
</nav>
```

I hope your answer is here?

Answer (score 0):

The proper jQuery code should look like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var widthWindow = $(window).width();
    if (widthWindow <= '767') {
        $('.yourElement').addClass('mobile');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.yourElement').removeClass('mobile');
    }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a small explanation as to why this is correct?